# Is it possible to make chromium instantly reload on tab crash?

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

We are running chromium 83 on an embedded system and experience some random tab crashes.

Is it possible to directly reload a tab in chromium, if it crashes (without showing the "Aw snap!" page)?

We're currently trying to patch the source code to get it working and those were our approaches so far.

(both in sad_tab_helper.cc -> SadTabHelper::RenderProcessGone()
Approach 1:

```
if (SadTab::ShouldShow(status)) {
  web_contents()->GetController().Reload(content::ReloadType::NORMAL, true);      
}
```

Approach 2:

```
if (SadTab::ShouldShow(status)) {
  content::RunOrPostTaskOnThread(
    FROM_HERE, 
    content::BrowserThread::ID::UI,
    base::BindOnce(
        [](content::WebContents* contents) {
          contents->GetController().Reload(content::ReloadType::NORMAL, true);
        },
        std::move(web_contents())));
}
```

Both changes finally lead to crash of the entire browser.

It seems that chromium tries to reload the page but as said, it then crashes. The log we get are:

```
[1663:1671:0321/090914.211931:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: http://127.0.0.1/login

[1663:1671:0321/090919.082378:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(40)] Recvmsg error: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

After that the entire browser crashes. Is there a way to do what we want or are we on a dead end here?

Comment: I don't think reloading is the solution to this problem. Maybe work on fixing that renderer process bug?

Comment: I totally agree. We're aware that it's an ugly workaround, but the browser has to run 24/7 and we could not make out the root cause within some weeks now and we need to ship soon. We already stepped back some chromium versions, because the problem does occur less frequently in the 83 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is suboptimal, `SadTabHelper::RenderProcessGone` only runs on UI.

Initiating navigation while handling notifications from any `WebContentsObserver` (`SadTabHelper` is a `WebContentsObserver`) must be avoided. It leads to problems. The both approaches attempt to do this. I suppose using `base::PostTask` instead of `content::RunOrPostTaskOnThread` should help.

```cpp
if (SadTab::ShouldShow(status)) {
  base::PostTask(
    FROM_HERE, 
    {content::BrowserThread::UI},
    base::BindOnce(
        [](content::WebContents* contents) {
          contents->GetController().Reload(content::ReloadType::NORMAL, true);
        },
        web_contents()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, after including the right header files, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is not good enough to comment so I can't leave this comment where it should be.

If you come across this particular solution, the required includes are:

```
#include "base/task_scheduler/post_task.h"
#include "content/public/browser/browser_thread.h"
#include "base/bind.h"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33792846)